# What happens to an MBS if all the underlying mortgages are fully paid back by the borrowers much before the maturity date?

Tags: macroeconomics, banking, investment, debt, securities

What would happen to an MBS (mortgage-backed security) if hypothetically speaking all the underlying mortgages were fully paid back by the mortgagees (borrowers), much before the maturity date?

I request the repliers of this question to follow this pattern:

- If the answer is w.r.t. a global context, please start it with "In a
  global context..." .
- If the answer is w.r.t. only a country(XYZ)'s
  context, please start it with "In XYZ , ....".

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the structure.

- In the US, most residential MBS are pass-through, so the MBS is prepaid.
- In Canada, MBS are (or at least were) mostly packaged into non-passthrough structures, so MBS cash flows follow fixed coupon schedule. There are prepayment penalties which are used to absorb the cash flows.
- My understanding is that European pfandebriefe markets use a collateral pool, which absorbs prepayments.

Comment: What is a logical reason(s) behind placing a penalty for pre-closure on the borrower? I can only see a greed-fuelled motive from the perspective of the investment bank, so as to keep a mortgage alive for ultimately being able to put it into an MBS.

Comment: If banks absorb prepayment risk, it is extremely difficult for them to duration match their portfolio. The lack of duration matching was a severe issue for banking systems in the 1970s. The US MBS market is somewhat unique in that the bond market absorbs prepayment risk.

Comment: And the Danish system is amazingly straightforward— borrowers can buy their own loan back out at the current market price.